# Gmail email not being sent when called from a threadpool

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, email

I'm trying to send email messages in an async manner, however when I call my SendMailMesage() method from within a Threadpool or a simple Thread, emails simply aren't sent.

Any way how to achieve this? Email sendind in a regular manner is considerably slowing down my application.

PS: if it matters, SendMailMesage() is being sent from a referenced project and not the MVC project itself.

Thanks.

**Edit:** My code.

```
namespace App.Core.Utils.Mailer
{
    public static class Sender
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a MailMessage object using the SMTP settings.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SendMailMessage(MailMessage message)
        {
            if (!Settings.Instance.SendEmails)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (message == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("message");

            try
            {
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                var smtp = new SmtpClient(Settings.Instance.SmtpServer);

                // don't send credentials if a server doesn't require it,
                // linux smtp servers don't like that 
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Instance.SmtpUserName))
                {
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Settings.Instance.SmtpUserName, Settings.Instance.SmtpPassword);
                }
                smtp.Port = Settings.Instance.SmtpServerPort;
                smtp.EnableSsl = Settings.Instance.EnableSsl;
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
            catch (SmtpException)
            {
                //OnEmailFailed(message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Remove the pointer to the message object so the GC can close the thread.
                message.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public static void SendMailMessageAsync(MailMessage message)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => SendMailMessage(message));
        } 
    }
}
```

Do note: this worked in WebForms. I copied the code to an MVC project, and now nothing gets sent if I call the `SendMailMessageAsync` method. No errors either.

Comment: Does it work when not called On the thread pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use this in MVC, and it works great. Since it implements an interface, you can inject an instance into the Controller constructor instead of using a static method:

```
public class MvcEmailSender : ISendEmails
{
    public MvcEmailSender(ILogExceptions logger, 
        IQueryEntities queryables, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        // save args to readonly fields on the instance
    }

    public void Send(EmailMessage message)
    {
        // constructor really passes more args here
        var sender = new SmtpEmailSender(message, arg2, arg3, arg4);
        var thread = new Thread(sender.Send);
        thread.Start();
    }
}

public class SmtpEmailSender
{
    private readonly EmailMessage _emailMessage;
    private int _retryCount;

    public SmtpEmailSender(EmailMessage emailMessage, ILogExceptions logger,
        IQueryEntities queryables, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        if (emailMessage == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("emailMessage");

        _emailMessage = emailMessage;
        // save other constructor args to readonly fields
    }

    public void Send()
    {
        try
        {
            // assemble message, send, & update database
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log exception, then retry like so:
            if (_retryCount++ <= 3)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Send();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We also have some settings provided in the web.config, do you? If so, update your question with the system.net section in your web.config.

To use this, we just call ISendEmails.Send(EmailMessage) from the controller. The implementation takes care of threading it, unbeknownst to MVC.

Both these 2 classes and the ISendEmails interface are declared in referenced projects, not the MVC project (the interface is in an API assembly and the 2 classes above are in an IMPL assembly).

**Update**

I've updated the code in response to the comment. Note the constructors of these classes really have more dependencies than were originally depicted. We also (constructor) inject ILogExceptions, IQueryEntities, and IUnitOfWork dependencies. Inside the try block, in addition to converting the EmailMessage to a MailMessage and sending, the EmailMessage domain object is updated in the database, and its SentOnUtc value is updated after SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage) succeeds. This is how we prove that emails were in fact sent. When an exception is caught, it is logged before the retry.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed worked. Would you care to explain how do you handly send retries in the commented code of your <code>Send()</code> method? :)